# Saving each close tick price to an array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to save "close price" of each tick into an array, then subtract the last 2 valves in the array to find the difference, but i can't get it to work properly.

```
var float difference = 0
var float[] arr = array.new_float(0)
if barstate.isrealtime
    array.push(arr, close)
    difference = (array.get(arr,array.size(arr)-1) - (array.get(arr,array.size(arr)-2)
label.new(bar_index,high,str.tostring(array.size(arr)) + '\n' + str.tostring(array.get(arr,0)),color=color.white)
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` is not your friend if you want to store data on every tick. You should use `varip` instead.

> ***varip (var intrabar persist)*** is the keyword used for assigning and
> one-time initializing of a variable. It is similar to the var keyword,
> but variables declared with varip retain their values between the
> updates of a real-time bar.